# Nativescript - App Tracking Transparency (ATT) framework

Tags: ios, admob, nativescript, apptrackingtransparency

I am using outdated plugin displaying ads via Google AdMob framework - https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-admob/

So far I have 2 iOS apps with AdMob interstitial ad displayed once after launch of the app.
The both are identical. Both have in Info.plist the same record:

```
    <key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
    <string>The app use data for tracking Opart users.</string>
```

First one passed review without any problem. The other one stuck rejected.

```
Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed


We're looking forward to completing the review of your app, but we need more information to continue. Specifically, we noticed that your app uses the AppTrackingTransparency framework, but we haven't been able to locate the relevant AppTrackingTransparency permission requests.

While it is not required to implement AppTrackingTransparency at this time, we check to make sure the implementation is compliant with our guidelines when we detect the framework in an app. 

Next Steps

If your app integrates AppTrackingTransparency, please indicate where in your app we can find the AppTrackingTransparency permission request.

If your app does not integrate AppTrackingTransparency, please indicate this information in the Review Notes section for each version of your app in App Store Connect when submitting for review.

Resources 
See the app privacy question update.
Learn more about how AppTrackingTransparency protects user's privacy and data.



Since your App Store Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit App Store Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and we will continue the review.
```

Q: Maybe anyone knows how to properly implement in Nativescript application  AppTrackingTransparency feaures?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have a look at this plugin (https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@nstudio/nativescript-tracking-transparency/). There is also roughly explained what you have to do.

```
// request access
TrackingTransparency.requestTrackingPermission().then(status => {
  if (status === TrackingStatus.Authorized) {
    // enable tracking features
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include the link to the plugin.